# Is it possible to have private computed properties in a Vue instance?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I sometimes use Vue for service classes as well as components.

In these cases reactive computeds are still extremely useful, but it would be nice to have a good way to mark which computeds are part of the public interface of the service class and which are private for internal calculation only.

With typescript it is easy to mark methods or properties as `private`, but I'm not sure if there is a good way to do this when defining computeds with `get`.

Is something like this the best path or is there a better way?

```
private get myComputed(): number {
  # ...
}
```

Comment: Are you using Vue 2 or Vue 3? And what does you "service classes" look like?

Comment: @Kapcash - Vue 2 with [vue-property-decorator](https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Using the new javascript private operator `#` will make the attribute unaccessible at runtime by the template or by using `refs`.
- Using the Typescript `private` keyword will make the field *look* private at build time and on the IDE, but when compiled, it's still accessible.

About computeds, you can use one of this solution:

```js
// supported from Typescript 4.3
get #myComputed () {
  return 'i am runtime private'
}

private get myComputed () {
  return 'i am build time private only'
}
```

---

Side note: to use vue reactivity for "services" and "helpers", I'd suggest to use the [@vue/composition-api](https://github.com/vuejs/composition-api) package for Vue 2. This way you can export composables (i.e. reactivity variables, computeds, watchers...) without actually creating a Vue component.

And you can make real private computeds, by not exporting them from your composable:

```js
export function useHelper () {
  const counter = ref(0)
  // "private" computed. Not visible from the composable clients
  const hasReachedMax = computed(() => counter > 10))

  const increment = () => {
    if(hasReachedMax) { return }
    counter.value++
  }
  
  return { counter, increment }
}
```